# Lazy require in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

My data (in react-native app) are currently retrieved this way:

```
let DB = (language) => (
    {
        data:() =>  {
            switch (language) {
                case "de":
                    return require("./de.json");
                case "en":
                    return require("./en.json");
                default:
                    return require("./en.json");
            }
    }})
```

how can I be sure those json are lazy loaded? An user want to load just the single json he needs.

Comment: ok I didn't know I can use a dynamic variable in require (since when?). Anyway, so do you confirm this solution (mine and yours) lazy-load the data?